# Is this valid? $r_1^3+r_2^3+\cdots+r_7^3=(r_1+\cdots + r_7)^3-3(r_1+\cdots+r_7)(r_1r_2+r_1r_3+\cdots+r_6r_7)+3(r_1r_2r_3+r_1r_2r_4+\cdots+r_5r_6r_7)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics, vieta-jumping

Is this a real formula? If not, is it a valid statement?

$$\begin{align}
r_1^3 + r_2^3 + r_3^3 + r_4^3 + r_5^3 + r_6^3 + r_7^3 &= (r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + r_4 + r_5 + r_6 + r_7)^3 \\
&- 3(r_1 + r_2 + \cdots + r_7)(r_1r_2 + r_1r_3 + \cdots + r_6r_7) \\
&+ 3(r_1r_2r_3 + r_1r_2r_4 + \cdots + r_5r_6r_7)
\end{align}$$

If this is real, is there a general formula for this that's not JUST $n = 7$? It can be any integer?

I'm trying to use this identity to solve this problem:

The polynomial $x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ has roots $r_1,$ $r_2,$ $\dots,$ $r_7.$ Calculate
$$\sum_{n = 1}^7 \left( r_n^3 + \frac{1}{r_n^3} \right).$$

So far, I have used the vieta's formula and I have made decent progress if that formula I stated above is true.

I'm stuck on another issue, however:

How to apply vieta's formula to this?

$$\frac {1} {r_1^3} + \frac {1} {r_2^3} + \frac {1} {r_3^3} + \frac {1} {r_4^3} + \frac {1} {r_5^3} + \frac {1} {r_6^3} + \frac {1} {r_7^3}$$

Comment: Look up "Newton's identities" to answer your first question(s). For your last question, note that if $r$ is a root of the given polynomial, then so is $1/r$ because the coefficients are "symmetric" in the sense that the coefficient of $x^k$ is the same as that of $x^{7-k}$.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel Arreola.

Comment: By the way, so is my formula wrong? How can I use newton's formula instead?

Comment: Using the notation from the wikipedia article, in general we have $p_3 = e_1^3 - 3e_1e_2 + 3e_3$, so your formula is correct. :)

Comment: So according to the Newton's formula, we have $r_1^3 + r_2^3 + ... + r_7^3 = (r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4+r_5+r_6+r_7)^3−3(r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4+r_5+r_6+r_7)(r_1r_2+r_1r_3+...+r_6r_7)+3(r_1r_2r_3+r_1r_2r_4...+r_5r_6r_7).$ 

When I plug in vieta's formula for the problem's given polynomial, $x^7+x^6+0x^5+x^4+x^3+0x^2+x+1,$


I simplify the newton's formula expression: $(-1)^3 - 3(-1)(0) + 3(-1) = -1 - 3 = -4$

Then, I got stuck trying to figure out how to solve

$$\frac {1} {r_1^3} + \frac {1} {r_2^3} + \frac {1} {r_3^3} + \frac {1} {r_4^3} + \frac {1} {r_5^3} + \frac {1} {r_6^3} + \frac {1} {r_7^3}$$

Comment: I just realized something!

$\frac {1} {r_1^3} + \frac {1} {r_2^3} + \frac {1} {r_3^3} + \frac {1} {r_4^3} + \frac {1} {r_5^3} + \frac {1} {r_6^3} + \frac {1} {r_7^3} = r_1^3 + r_2^3 + ... + r_7^3 = -4.$

Comment: So the answer is -4 + -4 = -8.

Comment: And it's correct! Thank you so much, Daniel Arreola!

Comment: I learned so much from this!

Comment: It's acceptable on MSE to answer your own Question, so if you want to do a full writeup as an Answer below, that would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a route using Newton's identities.  Here is just another way, perhaps simpler in this case:
$$x^7+x^6+x^4+x^3+x+1= (x+1)(x^6+x^3+1)=0$$
$$\implies (x+1)\left(x^3+\frac1{x^3}+1 \right)=0$$
So, apart from the root $x=-1$ say $r_1$, the rest of the roots satisfy $x^3+\dfrac1{x^3}=-1$.  Hence $$\sum_{n=1}^7\left(r_n^3+\frac1{r_n^3} \right)=-2+6\cdot(-1)=-8$$

Comment: Very nice and simple approach. +1